# Computing count up counter over elapsed time

Tags: javascript, jquery, server

I am trying to create a count up counter or ticket that shows "X amount of $ saved" over elapsed time.

This is what I have so far and it counts up no problem but it resets back to starting number once the page is refreshed.

```
var xmlHttp;
function srvTime(){
    try {
        //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (err1) {
        //IE
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (eerr3) {
                alert("AJAX not supported");
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    xmlHttp.send('');
    return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
}

var tick1 = 0;
var tick2 = 0;
var tick3 = 0;

function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}

function updateTicker() {
    $("#counter1").html(function (index, oldhtml) {
        tick1 += (6/5);
        return numberWithCommas( Math.floor(tick1) );
    });

    $("#counter2").html(function (index, oldhtml) {
        tick2 += (4.5/5);
        return numberWithCommas( Math.floor(tick2) );
    });

    $("#counter3").html(function (index, oldhtml) {
        tick3 += ((100/60)/5);
        return numberWithCommas( Math.floor(tick3) );
    });
}


var st = srvTime();
var date = new Date(st);
var tick = Math.floor((date.getTime() - 1349829008000) / 20000000);

tick1 = Math.floor(tick * (6/5));
tick2 = Math.floor(tick * (4.5/5));
tick3 = Math.floor(tick * ((100/60)/5));

$("#counter").html("" + numberWithCommas( tick1 ));
$("#counter2").html("" + numberWithCommas( tick2 ));
$("#counter3").html("" + numberWithCommas( tick3 ));

setInterval(function() {updateTicker();}, 60000);
```

Comment: When you page load ticks become are zero, because on refreshing js script is loading again, you should save old values at some storage cookies or server(usally I use it, but I think cookies will be better for this issue).

Comment: I don't think that the `srvTime()` function works as you expect it to. `XMLHttpRequest` performs an asynchronous operation, you need to wait until the `XMLHttpRequest` state is `HEADERS_RECEIVED` before calling `xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date")`

Comment: Show us the full code

Comment: @Nikita if I use cookies, can't the number reset back to original starting number if the user deletes the cookie? I am looking to store the counting number forever and keep on counting.

Comment: @codeapprentice Yes It will so, in this case you can use server, or if your application will work with large amount of people to reduce server load: save number at server, when man loads the application - check the cookies if it is empty load from server, when man closes the page - save number from cookie to the server. And also set at the server task to save the number to the server maybe one/two times a minute. This task will provide you minimal defense from hacks.

Comment: @codeapprentice When you set new number check cookie val and number in html if they not the same - user has deleted cookie, so load it from server. I not sure, but maybe there is a way to detect when cookies are deleted. If page is open you catch this event and save cookie val to the server. If page is close - it meens that on close event you have saved cookie val so if user delete cookie ot not it doesn't matter, because on load you should take it from server.

Comment: @codeapprentice The last: cookies are using for one session not as statick storage, it is like RAM on the PC. Usual scenario, for example some kind of editor: user load page, you load edit content to cookie, then user works and all changes are saving to cookie(so interface is fast), when user close the page, you save cookie to the server.